# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'cnt3' was corrupted

Tags: c++

В чём заключается ошибка и как это решить?

Само задание: https://prnt.sc/ZDSgfk2SLA-g

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<clocale>
int main(void) 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    char name1[9], name2[9], name3[9];
    char sc1, sc2, sc3;
    unsigned short cnt1, cnt2, cnt3;
    float sq1, sq2, sq3;
    printf("1.Введите: фирму, количество, объём, часть >");
    scanf("%s %c %d %f", name1, &sc1, &cnt1, &sq1);
    printf("2.Введите: фирму, количество, объём, часть >");
    scanf("%s %c %d %f", name2, &sc2, &cnt2, &sq2);
    printf("3.Введите: фирму, количество, объём, часть >");
    scanf("%s %c %d %f", name3, &sc3, &cnt3, &sq3);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|Фирмы - производители СКБД |\n");
    printf("|---------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("| Фирма | Количесво. Продуктов | Годовой объём продажи|Часть рынка|\n");
    printf("|----------|-------|-----------|-------------|\n");
    printf("| %9s | %c | %3d | %-5.1f |\n", name1, sc1, cnt1, sq1);
    printf("| %9s | %c | %3d | %-5.1f |\n", name2, sc2, cnt2, sq2);
    printf("| %9s | %c | %3d | %-5.1f |\n", name3, sc3, cnt3, sq3);
    printf("|---------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("| Примечание: по данным Gartner Group    |\n");
    printf("|        за 1999г               |\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то что-то не верится, что ваши 2480000000 влезут в `short int`...

Comment: Для начала - включить предупреждения компилятора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, вы используете `%d` для типа `short int`, т.е. записываете больше байт в памяти, чем передаете. Дали `%d` — используйте `int`.

Да и вообще-то что-то не верится, что ваши 2480000000 влезут даже в `int`, не говоря уж в `short int`. Я бы `long loing int` использовал (с соответствующим форматом в строке). Да и количество как `char` — странный выбор...